# Normalize subset of values of a dataframe given column label

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am reading data and storing it into a data frame (See below the data frame structure). Not sure if I will be able to clearly describe my question. I want to normalize every Makespan entry where Instances is **x** by the maximum and minimum Makespan value between the entries of Instances **x**.

```
import pandas as pd


# Read the data
data = ReadData()

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Instance', 'Instances', 'Makespan', 'MH'])

print(df)
```

The data frame looks like this:

```
    Instance Instances  Makespan  MH
0      mops1       1-5       345  DE
1      mops1       1-5       349  DE
2      mops1       1-5       345  DE
3      mops1       1-5       349  DE
4      mops1       1-5       349  DE
5      mops2       1-5       362  DE
6      mops2       1-5       362  DE
7      mops2       1-5       362  DE
8      mops2       1-5       362  DE
9      mops2       1-5       358  DE
10     mops3       1-5       409  DE
11     mops3       1-5       409  DE
12     mops3       1-5       409  DE
13     mops3       1-5       407  DE
14     mops3       1-5       409  DE
15     mops4       1-5       458  DE
16     mops4       1-5       458  DE
17     mops4       1-5       458  DE
18     mops4       1-5       458  DE
19     mops4       1-5       458  DE
20     mops5       1-5       509  DE
21     mops5       1-5       509  DE
22     mops5       1-5       513  DE
23     mops5       1-5       513  DE
24     mops5       1-5       509  DE
25     mops6      6-10       437  DE
26     mops6      6-10       435  DE
27     mops6      6-10       437  DE
28     mops6      6-10       437  DE
29     mops6      6-10       437  DE
..       ...       ...       ...  ..
364   mops14     11-15       413  TS
365   mops15     11-15       319  TS
366   mops15     11-15       319  TS
367   mops15     11-15       319  TS
368   mops15     11-15       319  TS
369   mops15     11-15       319  TS
370   mops16     16-20       543  TS
371   mops16     16-20       543  TS
372   mops16     16-20       543  TS
373   mops16     16-20       543  TS
374   mops17     16-20      1052  TS
375   mops17     16-20      1052  TS
376   mops17     16-20      1052  TS
377   mops17     16-20      1052  TS
378   mops17     16-20      1052  TS
379   mops18     16-20      3184  TS
380   mops18     16-20      3184  TS
381   mops18     16-20      3184  TS
382   mops18     16-20      3184  TS
383   mops18     16-20      3184  TS
384   mops19     16-20      1451  TS
385   mops19     16-20      1451  TS
386   mops19     16-20      1451  TS
387   mops19     16-20      1451  TS
388   mops19     16-20      1451  TS
389   mops20     16-20       541  TS
390   mops20     16-20       542  TS
391   mops20     16-20       545  TS
392   mops20     16-20       546  TS
393   mops20     16-20       542  TS
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your desired output?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Also, do note that variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.